# How can I clone a InnoDB table by coping disk file *.frm and *.ibd?

Tags: mysql

I want to clone an InnoDB table. 
Because of the large scale of data (nearly 10G), I'm tring to clone it by copy data file `*.frm` and `*.ibd`.

However, It didn't work.

Whatever I executed on the new copied table, it said:

`ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'XXX' doesn't exist`

So, how can I fix it ? or is there an efficient way to clone a large-scale table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed just copying the files is not enough. That's because in order for a table to work tablespace metadata InnoDB stores in *.ibd* file needs to match metadata stored in *ibdata1* file. That's why the recommended way of restoring InnoDB table is using backup tools like *mysqldump*.

There is however a way to make it work by copying files, but you need to take some extra actions to update tablespace metadata files. You can find detailed instructions here: http://www.chriscalender.com/tag/innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file/

Comment: The link is helpful to me.